# WebResource returning xml

Tags: java, xml, rest, jersey, jax-rs

How can I return a xml file after calling a particular WebResource?
My current one returns as a string

```
  WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://api.foursquare.com/v1/venues");
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
    queryParams.add("geolat", String.valueOf(lattitude));
    queryParams.add("geolong", String.valueOf(longitude));
    return webResource.queryParams(queryParams).get(String.class);
```

I later want to use XPath to parse the xml as it would be easier... is there a way to retrieve it directly to a .xml or do I have to create a xml from this string? If I have to then how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if the following would work, but it may be worth a try.

Change:

```
return webResource.queryParams(queryParams).get(String.class);
```

To:

```
return webResource.queryParams(queryParams).get(Source.class);
```

Alternatively you could use the java.net APIs and get the result as a stream.  The following example is taken from [my blog](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-55.html):

```
String uri =
    "http://localhost:8080/CustomerService/rest/customers/1";
URL url = new URL(uri);
HttpURLConnection connection =
    (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");

JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
InputStream xml = connection.getInputStream();
Customer customer =
    (Customer) jc.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(xml);

connection.disconnect();
```